# Problemas con col-xs (Boostrap)

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

EL problema es que en mi navegador no se ve correctamente los divs col-xs. No obstante aquí si se ve bien. Dejo una foto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
        <h1>Columna 1</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
        <h1>Columna 2</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
        <h1>Columna 3</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
    </div>

     <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
        <h1>Columna 1</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
        <h1>Columna 2</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
        <h1>Columna 3</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
    </div>

     <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
        <h1>Columna 1</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
        <h1> Columna 2</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
        <h1>Columna 3</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
        <h1>Columna 1</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
        <h1> Columna 2</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
        <h1>Columna 3</h1>
        <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Aquí](http://output.jsbin.com/diqibidupe) se muestra bien... cual navegador usas? Versiones? Haz limpiado el cache del navegador? ....

Comment: Que raro, borre chaché y además aqui se ve bien. No se que puede ser.  Navegador: Google chrome

Comment: Puede ser por <hr> agrega uno despues de tu ultima columna

Comment: Lo agregue y tampoco funciono

Comment: Aquí ni siquiera tienes el css de bootstrap enlazado, no sé como puedes verlo bien. De cualquier forma si no se puede reproducir el error es complicado saber que pasa ¿Tú codigo es exactamente el mismo que has puesto aquí?

Comment: ¿Con qué versión de Bootstrap es con la que estás trabajando?

Comment: Me lo descargue de la página oficial hace dos días, sera la última.

Comment: ¿4.0? Tengo toda la impresión de que por ahí va el problema.

Comment: Puede ser, en tal caso ¿Qué sucede?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema reside en las clases de grilla que estás usando para tus columnas. Las clases `col-xs` no funcionan para Bootstrap 4.

La versión 4.0 tiene opciones de grilla diferentes a las de la versión 3.x. Bootstrap 4 no cuenta con las clases `col-xs-` que tiene la versión 3.x para las pantallas de menor tamaño, pero sí cuenta con las clases `col-`, que cumplen el mismo propósito.

Eso si, debes tomar en cuenta, que las opciones de grilla tienen rangos de anchos de pantallas distintos entre versión y versión:

#### Bootstrap 4.0

- `col-`: Anchos bajo 576px
- `col-sm-`: Anchos entre 576px y 767px
- `col-md-`: Anchos entre 768px y 991px
- `col-lg-`: Anchos entre 992px y 1199px
- `col-xl-`: Anchos de 1200px en adelante

#### Bootstrap 3.x

- `col-xs-`: Anchos bajo 768px
- `col-sm-`: Anchos entre 768px y 991px
- `col-md-`: Anchos entre 992px y 1199px
- `col-lg-`: Anchos de 1200px en adelante

### Solución

Si estás usando Bootstrap 4, basta con reemplazar las clases `col-xs-` de tus columnas de la última fila, por las clases `col-`.

En este caso, `col-xs-4` por `col-4`:

```
<div class="col-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
  <h1>Columna 1</h1>
  <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
</div>
```

Tu fila quedaría así:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
      <h1>Columna 1</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
      <h1> Columna 2</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
      <h1>Columna 3</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

### Código completo

El código completo quedaría así:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
      <h1>Columna 1</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
     <h1>Columna 2</h1>
     <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
     <h1>Columna 3</h1>
     <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
      <h1>Columna 1</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
      <h1>Columna 2</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
      <h1>Columna 3</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
      <h1>Columna 1</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
      <h1> Columna 2</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
      <h1>Columna 3</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <hr>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
      <h1>Columna 1</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
      <h1> Columna 2</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
      <h1>Columna 3</h1>
      <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Y [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/CrisMVP3200/1esg7mnt/) lo puedes ver en acción.

### Véase también

- [Bootstrap 4: Grid options (Opciones de grilla)](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)
- [Bootstrap 3.3: Grid system (Sistema de grilla)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

Answer (score 1):

El código mas o menos debe de quedarte así, recuerda siempre considerar que versión de bootstarp estas usando.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
    <h1>Columna 1</h1>
    <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:#bbb">
    <h1> Columna 2</h1>
    <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
    <h1>Columna 3</h1>
    <p>Prueba de Bootstrap</p>
  </div>
</div>
```