# ¿Por qué se deforma esta imagen en dispositivos XS? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <!--Hide on screens wider than sm-->
    <div class="d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pl-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center text-center justify-content-center">
             <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 siguiente-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://mi.url.local/assets/images/mi-foto.png&quot;); height: 150px; max-height: 100%;"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-1">
                    <h4>fsffssdf</h4>
                    <h5>dsfdsfsdff</h5>
                    <span class="body-text block">fdfsfdfs</span>
                    <br/><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded">Btn</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.siguiente-image{
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 170px;
}
```

Quiero que la imagen se vea pequeña, pero en dispositivos XS se ve casi al 100%, no entiendo porqué se estira si está dentro de un col-sm-4 y col-xs-4, sin embargo, en dispositivos SM parece estar comportandose como espero.

Comment: Porque col-xs [ya no existe desde Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#global-changes).

Comment: Que debo hacer?

Comment: Si hacés clic en el enlace que proporcioné, se describe allí qué hacer :)

Comment: col-x es como anteriormente era col-xs-x?

Comment: No necesariamente. Es como decir _si no proporcionaste un `col-md-` o un `col-sm-`, tomo el valor por defecto, el cual está en `col-`_.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas con col-xs (Boostrap)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95108/problemas-con-col-xs-boostrap)

Comment: Asi es, muchas gracias